# How to get nested asparaenum properly indented?

Tags: indentation, enumitem, paralist

I'm using `asparaenum` to list some paragraphs, and they get indented properly.  But when I use nested `asparaenum`, the inner paragraphs get no indentation at all.  I wish them to have more indentation than the outer paragraphs.  Is it possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
\begin{asparaenum}
\item Sample paragraph 1.  This paragraph is only intended as a test and
    contains no information at all.
\item Sample paragraph 2.  This paragraph is properly intented.
    \begin{asparaenum}
    \item Sample paragraph a.  This paragraph is not indented.  How to fix
        this?
    \item Sample paragraph b.  This paragraph is not indented.  How to fix
        this?
    \end{asparaenum}
\item Sample paragraph 3.  This paragraph is only intended as a test and
    contains no information at all.
\end{asparaenum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide the LaTeX code as an example, starting with the documentclass and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with `enumitem`. The `asparaenum` environment corresponds to the `wide` option, with the difference that the item can have several paragraphs.

If the settings are to be used document-wise, they can be declared in the the preamble, with the`\setlist[listtype, level]{…}` command. Note that all horizontal parameters are relative to the higher level settings.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlist[enumerate, 1]{wide}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{wide = 2\parindent, leftmargin = \parindent}%
\setlist[enumerate, 3]{wide = 2\parindent, leftmargin = \parindent}%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[3]
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solves my problem.  But is it possible to automatically increase the indentation and avoid saying [wide=n\parindent] every time?

Comment: Yes, of course: use a `setlist` command in the preamble. See my updated answer.